# Android throwing up Error using jtwitter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a twitter application on Android target 2.2 (using some sample code that I found on the net and using Marko Gargenta's O'Reilly text). I am stuck with the problem as in the log below. The source code is given first followed by the log. Any idea what's going wrong here ? Also does anyone have or can point to a sample jtwitter code working on Android.

Thanks,
Ravi

---

```
protected String doInBackground(String... statuses) {
  try {

         //Autho information
         /*OAuthSignpostClient oauthclient = new OAuthSignpostClient(cons_key, 
           cons_secret, access_token, access_secret);*/

         OAuthSignpostClient oauthclient = new OAuthSignpostClient(access_token, access_secret,"oob");

         //***POSTING TO TWITTER CURRENTLY DOES NOT WORK WITH THIS INTERFACE
         twitter = new Twitter(mytwitterusername, oauthclient);
         //twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://learningandroid.status.net/api");

   //***POSTING TO TWITTER CURRENTLY DOES NOT WORK WITH THIS INTERFACE
   Log.i(Logtag, "Status currently is " + statuses[0]);

   Twitter.Status status = twitter.updateStatus(statuses[0]);
   //return status.text;
   return statuses[0];
  } catch (TwitterException e) {
   Log.e(Logtag, e.toString());
   e.printStackTrace();
   return "Failed to post to Twitter";
  }
```

}

---

### Log file:

```
E/dalvikvm(  719): Could not find method javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog, referenced from method winterwell.jtwi
tter.OAuthSignpostClient.askUser
W/dalvikvm(  719): VFY: unable to resolve static method 443: Ljavax/swing/JOptionPane;.showInputDialog (Ljava/lang/Objec
t;)Ljava/lang/String;
W/dalvikvm(  719): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
W/dalvikvm(  719): VFY:  rejected Lwinterwell/jtwitter/OAuthSignpostClient;.askUser (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Strin
g;
W/dalvikvm(  719): Verifier rejected class Lwinterwell/jtwitter/OAuthSignpostClient;
W/dalvikvm(  719): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  719): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:234)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:258)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: winterwell.jtwitter.OAuthSignpostClient
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at com.ravi.tweeto.StatusActivity$PostToTwitter.doInBackground(StatusActivity.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at com.ravi.tweeto.StatusActivity$PostToTwitter.doInBackground(StatusActivity.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256)
E/AndroidRuntime(  719):        ... 4 more
I/Process (  585): Sending signal. PID: 719 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  719): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  719): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
----
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically the JTwitter library has calls to Java swing classes that are not in the Android SDK as it does not use swing.  I had to get the source for JTwitter and remove the swing code for my application to work.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found most of the code I use somewhere on GitHub (can't find the exact link right now)
A few searches on snippets of the code send me [here](http://code.google.com/p/andtweet/), but I don't think that was the exact site I got it from.

But this is what I have in my semi-working code.

OAUTH.java

---

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class OAUTH extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "OAUTH";

public static final String USER_TOKEN = "user_token";
public static final String USER_SECRET = "user_secret";
public static final String REQUEST_TOKEN = "request_token";
public static final String REQUEST_SECRET = "request_secret";

public static final String TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
public static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
public static final String TWITTER_AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

private static final Uri CALLBACK_URI = Uri.parse("gpsagenda://twitt");

public static final String PREFS = "MyPrefsFile";

private OAuthConsumer mConsumer = null;
private OAuthProvider mProvider = null;

SharedPreferences mSettings;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    // We don't need to worry about any saved states: we can reconstruct the state
    mConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
            "myKey", 
            "mySecret");

    mProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider (
            TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, 
            TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
            TWITTER_AUTHORIZE_URL);

    // It turns out this was the missing thing to making standard Activity launch mode work
    mProvider.setOAuth10a(true);

    mSettings = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    if (i.getData() == null) {
        try {
                            // This is really important. If you were able to register your real callback Uri with Twitter, and not some fake Uri
                            // like I registered when I wrote this example, you need to send null as the callback Uri in this function call. Then
                            // Twitter will correctly process your callback redirection
            String authUrl = mProvider.retrieveRequestToken(mConsumer, CALLBACK_URI.toString());
            saveRequestInformation(mSettings, mConsumer.getToken(), mConsumer.getTokenSecret());
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && CALLBACK_URI.getScheme().equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        String token = mSettings.getString(OAUTH.REQUEST_TOKEN, null);
        String secret = mSettings.getString(OAUTH.REQUEST_SECRET, null);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailsContainer.class); // Currently, how we get back to main activity.

        try {
            if(!(token == null || secret == null)) {
                mConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
            }
            String otoken = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            // We send out and save the request token, but the secret is not the same as the verifier
            // Apparently, the verifier is decoded to get the secret, which is then compared - crafty
            // This is a sanity check which should never fail - hence the assertion
            Assert.assertEquals(otoken, mConsumer.getToken());

            // This is the moment of truth - we could throw here
            mProvider.retrieveAccessToken(mConsumer, verifier);
            // Now we can retrieve the goodies
            token = mConsumer.getToken();
            secret = mConsumer.getTokenSecret();
            OAUTH.saveAuthInformation(mSettings, token, secret);
            // Clear the request stuff, now that we have the real thing
            OAUTH.saveRequestInformation(mSettings, null, null);
            i.putExtra(USER_TOKEN, token);
            i.putExtra(USER_SECRET, secret);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            startActivity(i); // we either authenticated and have the extras or not, but we're going back
            finish();
        }
    }
}

public static void saveRequestInformation(SharedPreferences settings, String token, String secret) {
    // null means to clear the old values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    if(token == null) {
        editor.remove(OAUTH.REQUEST_TOKEN);
        Log.d(TAG, "Clearing Request Token");
    }
    else {
        editor.putString(OAUTH.REQUEST_TOKEN, token);
        Log.d(TAG, "Saving Request Token: " + token);
    }
    if (secret == null) {
        editor.remove(OAUTH.REQUEST_SECRET);
        Log.d(TAG, "Clearing Request Secret");
    }
    else {
        editor.putString(OAUTH.REQUEST_SECRET, secret);
        Log.d(TAG, "Saving Request Secret: " + secret);
    }
    editor.commit();

}

public static void saveAuthInformation(SharedPreferences settings, String token, String secret) {
    // null means to clear the old values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    if(token == null) {
        editor.remove(OAUTH.USER_TOKEN);
        Log.d(TAG, "Clearing OAuth Token");
    }
    else {
        editor.putString(OAUTH.USER_TOKEN, token);
        Log.d(TAG, "Saving OAuth Token: " + token);
    }
    if (secret == null) {
        editor.remove(OAUTH.USER_SECRET);
        Log.d(TAG, "Clearing OAuth Secret");
    }
    else {
        editor.putString(OAUTH.USER_SECRET, secret);
        Log.d(TAG, "Saving OAuth Secret: " + secret);
    }
    editor.commit();

}

}
```

---

DetailsTwitter.java (my "implementation")

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;

import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.gpsagenda.OAUTH;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DetailsTwitter extends Activity {

    public SharedPreferences mSettings;

    private LinkedList<UserStatus> mHomeStatus = new LinkedList<UserStatus>();
    public String mToken;
    public String mSecret;
    private OAuthConsumer mConsumer = null;
    private HttpClient mClient;
    private EditText mEditor;
    private TextView mLast;
    private CheckBox mCB;
    private Button mButton;
    private TextView mUser;
    private int ID;

    public static final String VERIFY_URL_STRING = "http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.json";
    public static final String PUBLIC_TIMELINE_URL_STRING = "http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json";
    public static final String USER_TIMELINE_URL_STRING = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json";
    public static final String HOME_TIMELINE_URL_STRING = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json";   
    public static final String FRIENDS_TIMELINE_URL_STRING = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/friends_timeline.json"; 
    public static final String STATUSES_URL_STRING = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json"; 

    ProgressDialog postDialog = null;

    public static final String TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    public static final String TWITTER_AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize";



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailstwittertab); 

        HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(parameters, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(parameters, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(parameters, false);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(parameters, true);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(parameters, 8192);

        SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
        schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        ClientConnectionManager tsccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(parameters, schReg);
        mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(tsccm, parameters);

        mCB = (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.enable);
        mCB.setChecked(false);
        mEditor = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editor);
        mButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.post);
        mUser = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.user);
        mLast = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.last);


        mSettings = getSharedPreferences(OAUTH.PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
            "myKey", 
            "mySecret");
    }

    public void PostTweet(View v) {
        String postString = mEditor.getText().toString();
        if (postString.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.tweet_empty), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            BitlyAndroid bitly = new BitlyAndroid("iarwain01", "R_1bffd0176aa731a27e5b2d23cf043199");
            String shortUrl = "";
            // Try to get the corresponding ID of the POI
           try
           {
               ID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
           } catch (NullPointerException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
            try {
                shortUrl = bitly.getShortUrl("http://gpsagenda.ikdoeict.be/projecten2/index.php?module=places&id=" + ID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Link shortening failed!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new PostTask().execute(postString + " " + shortUrl);
        }
    }

    protected void onFinish() {
        mClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    public void ConnectWithTwitter(View v)
    {
        if(mCB.isChecked()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, OAUTH.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            OAUTH.saveAuthInformation(mSettings, null, null);
            mButton.setEnabled(false);
            mEditor.setEnabled(false);
            mCB.setChecked(false);
            mUser.setText("");
        }
        mCB.setChecked(false); // the oauth callback will set it to the proper state
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        // We look for saved user keys
        if(mSettings.contains(OAUTH.USER_TOKEN) && mSettings.contains(OAUTH.USER_SECRET)) {
            mToken = mSettings.getString(OAUTH.USER_TOKEN, null);
            mSecret = mSettings.getString(OAUTH.USER_SECRET, null);
            if(!(mToken == null || mSecret == null)) {
                mConsumer.setTokenWithSecret(mToken, mSecret);
            }
        }
        new GetCredentialsTask().execute();
    }

    // These parameters are needed to talk to the messaging service
    public HttpParams getParams() {
        // Tweak further as needed for your app
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        // set this to false, or else you'll get an Expectation Failed: error
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);

        return params;
    }

    //----------------------------
    // This task posts a message to your message queue on the service.
    private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        ProgressDialog postDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            postDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DetailsTwitter.this, 
                    getText(R.string.tweet_progress_title), 
                    getText(R.string.tweet_progress_text), 
                    true,   // indeterminate duration
                    false); // not cancel-able
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

            JSONObject jso = null;
            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json");
                LinkedList<BasicNameValuePair> out = new LinkedList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                out.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", params[0]));
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(out, HTTP.UTF_8));
                post.setParams(getParams());
                // sign the request to authenticate
                mConsumer.sign(post);
                String response = mClient.execute(post, new BasicResponseHandler());
                jso = new JSONObject(response);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }
            return jso;
        }

        // This is in the UI thread, so we can mess with the UI
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jso) {
            postDialog.dismiss();
            if(jso != null) { // authorization succeeded, the json object contains the user information
                mEditor.setText("");
                mLast.setText(getCurrentTweet(jso));
            } else {
                mLast.setText(getText(R.string.tweet_error));
            }
        }
    }

    // Get stuff from the two types of Twitter JSONObject we deal with: credentials and status 
    private String getCurrentTweet(JSONObject status) {
        return status.optString("text", getString(R.string.bad_value));
    }

    //----------------------------
    // This task is run on every onResume(), to make sure the current credentials are valid.
    // This is probably overkill for a non-educational program
    private class GetCredentialsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

        ProgressDialog authDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            authDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DetailsTwitter.this, 
                getText(R.string.auth_progress_title), 
                getText(R.string.auth_progress_text), 
                true,   // indeterminate duration
                false); // not cancel-able
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            JSONObject jso = null;
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(VERIFY_URL_STRING);
            try {
                mConsumer.sign(get);
                String response = mClient.execute(get, new BasicResponseHandler());
                jso = new JSONObject(response);
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jso;
        }

        // This is in the UI thread, so we can mess with the UI
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jso) {
            authDialog.dismiss();
            mCB.setChecked(jso != null);
            mButton.setEnabled(jso != null);
            mEditor.setEnabled(jso != null);
            mUser.setText(jso != null ? getUserName(jso) : getString(R.string.userhint));
            mLast.setText(jso != null ? getLastTweet(jso) : getString(R.string.userhint));
            if(jso != null) {
                TimelineSelector ss = new TimelineSelector(HOME_TIMELINE_URL_STRING);
                new GetTimelineTask().execute(ss);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getLastTweet(JSONObject credentials) {
        try {
            JSONObject status = credentials.getJSONObject("status");
            return getCurrentTweet(status);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return getString(R.string.tweet_error);
        }
    }

    private String getUserName(JSONObject credentials) {
        return credentials.optString("name", getString(R.string.bad_value));
    }

    private class TimelineSelector extends Object {
        public String url; // the url to perform the query from
        // not all these apply to every url - you are responsible
        public Long since_id; // ids newer than this will be fetched
        public Long max_id; // ids older than this will be fetched
        public Integer count; // # of tweets to fetch Max is 200
        public Integer page; // # of page to fetch (with limits)

        public TimelineSelector(String u) {
            url = u;
            max_id = null;
            since_id = null;
            count = null;
            page = null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public TimelineSelector(String u, Long since, Long max, Integer cnt, Integer pg) {
            url = u;
            max_id = max;
            since_id = since;
            count = cnt;
            page = pg;
        }
    }

    private class UserStatus {

        JSONObject mStatus;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        JSONObject mUser;

        public UserStatus(JSONObject status) throws JSONException {

            mStatus = status;
            mUser = status.getJSONObject("user");
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public long getId() {
            return mStatus.optLong("id", -1);
        }
        /*public String getUserName() {
            return mUser.optString("name", getString(R.string.bad_value));
        }
        public String getText() {
            return getCurrentTweet(mStatus);
        }
        public String getCreatedAt() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Time ret1 = new Time();
            return mStatus.optString("created_at", getString(R.string.bad_value));
        }*/
    }

    private class GetTimelineTask extends AsyncTask<TimelineSelector, Void, JSONArray> {


        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(TimelineSelector... params) {
            JSONArray array = null;
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
                    Uri sUri = Uri.parse(params[i].url);
                    Uri.Builder builder = sUri.buildUpon();
                    if(params[i].since_id != null) {
                        builder.appendQueryParameter("since_id", String.valueOf(params[i].since_id));
                    } else if (params[i].max_id != null) { // these are mutually exclusive
                        builder.appendQueryParameter("max_id", String.valueOf(params[i].max_id));
                    }
                    if(params[i].count != null) {
                        builder.appendQueryParameter("count", String.valueOf((params[i].count > 200) ? 200 : params[i].count));
                    }
                    if(params[i].page != null) {
                        builder.appendQueryParameter("page", String.valueOf(params[i].page));
                    }
                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(builder.build().toString());
                    mConsumer.sign(get);
                    String response = mClient.execute(get, new BasicResponseHandler());
                    array = new JSONArray(response);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return array;
        }

        // This is in the UI thread, so we can mess with the UI
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray array) {
            if(array != null) {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
                        JSONObject status = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        UserStatus s = new UserStatus(status);
                        mHomeStatus.add(s);
                    }
                    //mAA.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

My AndroidManifest.xml

---

```
    <activity android:name="DetailsTwitter" />
    <activity android:name="OAUTH" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="gpsagenda" android:host="twitt" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

This should be enough to get you going, I hope.

If something is wrong in here, pleas do comment.

Regards,

iarwain

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking at using the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library as an alternative. I've had no issues using it within an Android application.