# Token library for Sociallib

Tags: android, twitter, token

im going to use Sociallib library in my app to interact with social networks. I referred to [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/sociallib/wiki/SocialLibGuide) for some guidance. As external JARs im using following libraries:

- signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar
- signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar
- SocialLibBeta2_2.jar

But, when i trying this code to get Tokens, it requires Token class for implementation.

```
Token at = twitter.getAccessToken();
String token = at.getToken(); //You can store these two strings
String secret = at.getSecret();//in order to build the token back
```

I would be thankful if someone may tell me where can i find this library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Sociallib now you missing another 2 libs, i think you should see [this](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/list) and [this](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe/downloads) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841501/example-project-tutorial-for-demonstration-of-different-features-of-sociallibs-i)